# Automapper - Quick custom map

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, automapper

I want to do a quick an easy mapping from a `DateTime src` to a `DateTime? dest` such that if `src == DateTime.MinValue` it will set `dest = null`.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this that doesn't require making a new mapping resolver?

Will it suffice to do `/*other stuff*/.ForMember(d=>d.dest, opt=>opt.MapFrom(s=>(s.src == DateTime.MinValue)?null:s.src);`

**Edit**

The above statement yields the error

"Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'DateTime'."

But when I typecast both outputs of the conditional statement to `DateTime?` it gets rid of the error. The new statement becomes `/*other stuff*/.ForMember(d => d.dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => (s.src == DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?)s.src);`

**Edit 2**

Here are stripped down version of the actual classes.

```
public class Foo{
    ...
    public DateTime TimeIssued { get; set;}
    ...
}

public class FooViewModel{
    ...
    public DateTime? TimeIssued { get; set;}
    ...
    public static List<FooViewModel> From(List<Foo> foos){
        return Mapper.Map<List<FooViewModel>>(foos);
    }
}

/*elsewhere, in the automapper configuration file*/

Mapper.CreatMap<Foo, FooViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TimeIssued, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (src.TimeIssued == DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?) src.TimeIssued));
```

I would like `FooViewModel.TimeIssued` to be `null` when the passed in `Foo.TimeIssued` is `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Did you try if it will suffice?

Comment: "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'DateTime'."

Comment: maybe not the 'quick' solution you're looking for, but you can use a type converter like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672008/how-to-handle-invalid-dates-with-automapper/59673429#59673429)

Comment: You can't just try to insert a Nullable (Datetime) type to a non nullable(DateTime). You either have to make your "dst" a Nullable<DateTime> OR instead of (Datetime?)null you need to set it to another Datetime (such as DateTime.Now or DateTime.MinValue and so forth)

Comment: 1. The destination is nullable, the source isnt. I want the destination to be null if the source is DateTime.MinValue.
2. Whats the difference between `Nullable<DateTime>` and `DateTime?`?

Comment: Please add whole mapping configuration and classes.

Comment: Done. Hope its to your liking.

Comment: @Ilan_Schindler you get compile time error cause cause compiler can't infer common base type for `null` and `DateTime`. You don't need to add `DateTime?` to both outputs, one is fine (any).

Comment: You only need to cast one side of the conditional btw. That will make it look cleaner but that should be exactly what you need